# MySQL added the date to a many to many table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have three tables, the first two are used to store information about people.

So how do I add the date to the link the 3 tables?

Trying to practice my school work at home and have no idea how to do this!
Edit: all I can think off would be this SELECT B.Date_of_exams, C.last_name, B.subjects_name

Comment: You are trying to join tables. This is a very common practice in SQL, and I think you can quitte easily find the answer if you'd search some more.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want, you need to join the tables using INNER JOIN like this:

```
SELECT B.Date_of_exams, C.last_name, B.subjects_name
FROM 
entries A
INNER JOIN subjects B
ON A.subjects = B.subjects_id
INNER JOIN students C
ON A.student = C.student_id
```

Comment: Thanks so much as I have been struggling with this for over 2 weeks.

Comment: Does it help? If yes, you can accept this as answer. Additionally if you struggle with this basic sql concept, I suggest you to take sql basic course here: http://www.sqlcourse.com/

Comment: Cant accept this as answer for 3 mins but i will do soon and thanks for the link I will look at that tonight!